# Categories in menu navigation drawer

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

How to implement menu navigation drawer, when user click some item of menu,menu list swipe to new menu list. All of this happen in menu navigation drawer.
There is the screen

It is when menu navigation drawer open

[image]

This is when user clicked second item

[image]

And finally when user clicked some item

[image]

Comment: use navigation view for this functionality instead of navigation drawer

Comment: @KeyurLakhani  
I have to swipe all navigation view to new view. If I use expandable list, i steal use old view. I confuce please give me some example link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fragment with listView. when you click on a item, A new Fragment will override the screen. There you need to manage to show content.

you also need to store all fragment in a backstack, so you can go back to previous fragment.

Demo Link :- `https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2eu2hl117t6v1x/main.rar?dl=0`

APK Link :- `https://www.dropbox.com/s/8h2zr8ah2dxgik3/app-debug.apk?dl=0`

Comment: I have to swipe all navigation view to new view. If I use expandable list, i steal use old view. I confuce please give me some example link

Comment: Where I need to  implement overiding fragment. There ? public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {...}

Comment: then at runtime load fragment with listview at that framelayout

Comment: sorry but I am new in android, please give me a link where implement this example

Comment: I think the problem here is how to show a different drawer menu when you press an item in the current menu.

Comment: Well you achieve this by many way. I will try wat ever suit current condition

Comment: @user3641702 :- Check my answer. I updated it by APK, and code. User can modify code according to their need. I created it in hurry.. But working great.

Comment: @user3641702 :- I can ac chive, these type of thing in many ways.. I just shared a idea that time, that come instantly in my mind. And see it become reality.

Comment: @Himanshu Shekher Jha Thank you for your help, I'll take a look at what you posted